# Issue with upadating xml file using java?

Tags: java, xml, parsing, jakarta-ee, xml-parsing

//**Am getting null at              NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(e); Below is my xml content
Am trying to delete similar tags present in the xml file. nList is showing null. How to approach the problem?

**

```
    public class DelElement {
public static String parent;
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        File file = new File("D:/vodafone/parse.xml");

        DocumentBuilder dBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance()
        .newDocumentBuilder();

        Document doc = dBuilder.parse(file);

        System.out.println("Root element :" + doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName());
        parent=doc.getDocumentElement().getNodeName();
        if (doc.hasChildNodes()) {

            printNote(doc,doc.getChildNodes());

        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}

private static void printNote(Document doc, NodeList nodeList) throws TransformerException {



    String file = "D:/vodafone/parse.xml";

    for (int count = 0; count < nodeList.getLength(); count++) {

        Node tempNode = nodeList.item(count);

        // make sure it's element node.
        if (tempNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {

            // get node name and value
            System.out.println("\nNode Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [OPEN]");
            System.out.println("Node Value =" + tempNode.getTextContent());

            if(tempNode.getNodeName()!=parent){





                System.out.println("----------------------------");



                if (tempNode.getChildNodes().getLength()>1){
                    NodeList nodeMap=tempNode.getChildNodes();
                    System.out.println("inside del");

                    for (int i=0;i<nodeMap.getLength();i++){



                        String e = "'"+(String)nodeMap.item(i).getNodeName()+"'";

                        System.out.println("inside del node:"+e);
                        NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(e);

                        if (nList.getLength()>1){

                            for (int con=1;i==nList.getLength()-1;con++){

                                Element el = (Element)nList.item(con);
                                System.out.println("element"+el);
                                System.out.println("parent"+el.getParentNode());
                                el.getParentNode().removeChild(el);
                            }
                            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();

                            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                            transformer.setOutputProperty(OutputKeys.INDENT, "yes");
                            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(file));
                            transformer.transform(source, result);
                        }
                    }}}

            if (tempNode.hasChildNodes()) {

                // loop again if has child nodes
                printNote(doc, tempNode.getChildNodes());

            }

            System.out.println("Node Name =" + tempNode.getNodeName() + " [CLOSE]");

        }

    }

}}
```

Comment: <check>
<sai>
<test value="hai"/>
<test value="hai"/> 
<test value="hai"/> 
</sai>
<dinesh>
<test value="hai"/>
<test value="hai"/>
</dinesh>
</check>

Comment: In the above tags am trying to delete <test> tags present inside <sai> and <dinesh> tags.

Comment: Please edit your question rather than adding comments.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be in your "for loop" where you are trying to delete the nodes. Your loop says:: "for (int con=1;i==nList.getLength()-1;con++){" ... Based on your code, the condition to break the loop "i==nList.getLength()-1" is always true so it never ends up going inside that block...

I believe, this is what you should be doing (still feels a little convoluted way to do a very small job; But I'm guessing you are just sharing part of the puzzle... See below; this will delete the nodes...

```
                        for (int con=nList.getLength()-1; con>=0; con--) {
                            Element el = (Element)nList.item(con);
                            System.out.println("element"+el);
                            System.out.println("parent"+el.getParentNode());
                            el.getParentNode().removeChild(el);
                        }
                        /*
                        for (int con=1;i==nList.getLength()-1;con++){

                            Element el = (Element)nList.item(con);
                            System.out.println("element"+el);
                            System.out.println("parent"+el.getParentNode());
                            el.getParentNode().removeChild(el);
                        }
                        */
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: No. am getting null at NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(e);
here e='test'..

Comment: Instead of tag name, am using this:
if (tempNode.getChildNodes().getLength()>1){
NodeList nList=tempNode.getChildNodes();
 for (int con = nList.getLength()-1; con>0; con--){
}
Here  nList.getLength() is returning 7.. Its printing this:
**element[#text: **

]

Comment: First off, by "getting null" do you mean that the program is throwing NullPointerException? Because it's not doing that for me. Can you share your exact code? Also what version of Java are you using?

Comment: I have changed it. tnx..no problem now.. The newer problem is--
 "What to do if I have to delete all the nodes, except one, having same tag name and attribute value? Like <test name="sai"/><test name="sai"/> Here I have to delete one complete node <test name="sai"/> when both attribute and node name are same?"

Answer (score 0):

Use Xpath:

```
    Document doc = ...
    XPath xp = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xp.evaluate("//sai/test | //dinesh/test", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
        Node node = nodes.item(i);
        node.getParentNode().removeChild(node);
    }

    TransformerFactory tf ....
```

UPDATE:

The code above is just an example of what you can do: Another approach could be to find all element nodes that have more than one <test> child, and then do some further processing to remove duplicates:

```
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xp.evaluate("//node()[count(./test) > 1", doc, XPathConstants.NODESET);
    for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); ++i) {
        Node parent= nodes.item(i);
        checkAndRemoveDuplicates(parent);
    }
```

The point of it all is that XPath is a powerful tool that can help you solve the problem with a lot less code.

Comment: Here I should check if there are more than one node with same name...then deletion of all copies must be done except one.

Comment: Feel free to do whatever you want.

Comment: What to do if I have to delete all the nodes, except one, having same tag name and attribute value?
Like <test name="sai"/><test name="sai"/> Here I have to delete one complete node <test name="sai"/> when both attribute and node name are same?

Answer (score -1):

It looks like when you're calling

```
doc.getElementsByTagName(e);
```

the value of e is something like "'test'". However the element name itself in the XML is just "test" (no single quotes). That's likely your culprit

Comment: I only added the single quote later. I tried without that too.. It's still returning null.